# Regex for matching a character without leading and trailing spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

How to find regex for matching a character without leading and trailing spaces
Example : "This is a sample String"
Need a regex for capturing character "a" like.
This is a s**a**mple String.

Thanks

Comment: Try `/(?<=\S)+a(?=\S+)/g`

Comment: Thanks, With small change((?<=\S)a(?=\S+)) in yours regex, its works.

Comment: I have posted an answer, please check if it works for you.

Comment: Did you tried the answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the original question is intended to solve the question by RegExp in JavaScript, here I provided an approach for the topic purely focusing on the expression itself.

As we all know, regular expression is very powerful, but different language have subtle difference upon its implementations. The one should be more carefully is different browser may also have different supports. Although the [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind) of **RegExp Lookbehind Assertions`(?<=...)`** have been reached stage 4 in TC39, its implementation is not yet guaranteed to be shipped. (e.g. it is not supported in Safari 11.1).

Although starting from Chrome 62 **`(?<=...)`** have been supported, but it still not out as ECMAS2018 (well... it is very likely to be included in ECMA2019 released at this year). I won't suggest to use it. (unless your are running server side code, where it supported, e.g. in PHP, or Node.js > 9).

A less verbose approach in JavaScript have been suggested, which is always recommended to preprocess your string by splitting it into array and match out your array by `Array.map` or `Array.filter` using regular expression. But what if your question is even complicated? or for some reason you just want to use regular expression?!

Unfortunately, because **Lookbehind Assertions** is not fully adapted and available to everyone, a much close approach is to execute multiple regular expressions, i.e. find out a pattern in one RegExp and then perform another RegExp on the matched result.

Here I think people may try `/(?:[^\s])(a)(?:[^\s])/g` instead:

`(?:...)` assertion will ensure `...` will be matched but not captured in the group.

`[^/s]` exclude the space and it just need to match once, unless you want your full match to match more characters.

`(...)` will be captured in the first group. In this case, `...` is `a`.

Again, without **Lookbehind Assertions** in JavaScript, it is not possible to match a pattern without capturing its neighboured. So another regular expression is needed to handle the full match in `String.replace` or `String.match` operation.  Here is the example:

```
"This is a sample String.".replace(/(?:[^\s])(a)(?:[^\s])/g,
     (fullmatch, group) => fullmatch.replace(/a/, `<strong>${group}</strong>`));
```

, which outputs `"This is a s<strong>a</strong>mple String.`

Finally, as highly be recommended, people may want to use a live tool to testify an expression first. Try this: https://regex101.com